# More than+ noun

Tags: adverbial-phrases

In the following sentence

> More than 60% of the population ***lives*** below poverty line.

I think *live* will be correct instead of lives. 
Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: "Population" is a singular noun, but it's a collective so plural override is possible. I believe that in AmE, singular is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

> More than 60% population lives below poverty line.

The correct verb form in English for noun phrases that refer to groups or collections is not well-defined, and is noticeably regional.

Most *American* native English speaker would say "lives", but I think the British would tend to say "live".

> Correct me if i were wrong.

Correct me if *I am* wrong.